# Copy Data from Access to an Existing SQL Server Table

Tags: c#, winforms

This code copies data from access to SQL server table.
but this code has some problems.

1. This code can not copy data from access to SQL server table where have data.

My SQL server table has some data and I want to add data from access to under existing data in SQL server table.

How do I add data to the existing table?

2. Can not read data from access 2007 or 2010.

How do I read data from access 2007/2010

```
OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
         openfiledialog1.Title = "select access file";

            openfiledialog1.Filter = "Access 2003 (*.mdb)|*.mdb|Access 2007|*.accdb";
            if (openfiledialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + openfiledialog1.FileName;
                const string connectionStringDest = @"server=ahmad-pc\anfd;database = phonebook;Integrated Security = true";
                using (var sourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    sourceConnection.Open();

                    var commandSourceData = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from numberperson", sourceConnection);
                    var reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

                    using (var destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringDest))
                    {
                        destinationConnection.Open();

                        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                        {


                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "nameperson"); //THIS A MAPPING REPLACE IT WITH YOUR NEED
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("family", "family1");
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "profile2";

                            try
                            {
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                reader.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("success");
                }

            }
```

Comment: You should change your connection string based on the ms-access version of the file. Here's 2007: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007

Answer (score 0):

SQLBulkCopy only does Bulk inserts so any existing data should not be modified.

For MS Access > 2003 you'll need to use Microsoft ACE instead of JET

Comment: I should use what function instead SQLBulkCopy ?

Comment: @anfd I don't think bulk copy deletes any data, so using it should be fine.